# How does page.tpl.php come into action?

Tags: theming

When the line `<?php print $page; ?>` is encountered in the html.tpl.php template, what happens that make the page template (page.tpl.php) come into action?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the other way around; it's the theming of the page template that invokes the theming of the html template (as strange as that might sound).

When Drupal goes to serve a normal HTML page (through [`drupal_deliver_html_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7)), it calls [`drupal_render_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_page/7). To get the basic render array for the page, that function invokes [`hook_element_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7) with the 'page' argument.

The [`system_element_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_element_info/7) function defines that type like this:

```
$types['page'] = array(
  '#show_messages' => TRUE, 
  '#theme' => 'page', 
  '#theme_wrappers' => array('html'),
);
```

When the `drupal_render_page()` function eventually gets around to calling `drupal_render()` on the `$page` array (once it's been populated with the page content/blocks/etc), `theme_page()` is called with the `$page` element as it's 'render element', and the return from that call is passed to the theme wrapper ([`theme_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!theme.php/function/theme_html/7)).

It's that return value that populates the `$page` variable in html.tpl.php

Comment: sir,i am beginner in drupal theming. this example too advance for me. i understand nothing crystal clear. so can you please explain this answer in simple words or step by step processes occur at this stage i am highly thanksfull for your kindness

Comment: There's no simpler way to explain it really; if you're just a beginner to theming then I wonder why you need to know the internals of the theming system?

Comment: actually sir , i try make picture in mind how drupal make whole page step by step.but page cycle of druapl and rendering concept puzzle me a lot. so please help me!